# RPM build issues

Tags: linux, rpm

I have an RPM spec file like this, I have compiled a C file and created an executable and trying to copy it to buildroot/tmp folder and trying to execute it from there,

```
%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/tmp/
install -m 755 /root/Desktop/np %{buildroot}/tmp/np
./%{buildroot}/tmp/np
%files
/tmp/np
```

When I try to build the RPM, I am facing an error

> "/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.0HMeZn: line 35:
>   .//root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/hp-simulate-generalfailure1-1.0.0-1.x86_64/tmp/np:
>   No such file or directory"

Help me out to make a clean build. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have removed the trailing / character in ./%{buildroot}/tmp/np.

Comment: Now it looks like .%{buildroot}/tmp/np. Even with this, running into the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Let's put aside that you are doing something very strange and executing rpmbuild as root (very nasty).

The `%{buildroot}` is an absolute path. See:

```
$ rpm --eval '%{buildroot}'
/home/msuchy/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}.x86_64
```

If you are really trying to execute that binary, you should not put the leading `./` there. So you snippet should be:

```
%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/tmp/
install -m 755 /root/Desktop/np %{buildroot}/tmp/np
%{buildroot}/tmp/np
%files
/tmp/np
```

Answer (score 0):

Running anything in `%install` section will occur only on the build machine, during rpm build process. It will *not* happen when you install the RPM.

To run something upon package installation, you have to make use of scriplets:

```
%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/tmp/
install -m 755 /root/Desktop/np %{buildroot}/tmp/np

%files
/tmp/np

%post
/tmp/np
```

In example above, `/tmp/np` will be executed when package is either installed for the first time, or upgraded.